# Atomic multi-entry operations on ConcurrentHashMap

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, concurrenthashmap, atomic

I need to perform a two-entries concurrent operation on a `ConcurrentHashMap`atomically.

I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` of `Client`, with an `Integer id` as *key*; every client has a `selectedId` attribute, which contains the id of another client or itself (means nobody selected).

At every `clientChangedSelection(int whoChangedSelection)` concurrent event, I need to check atomically if both the client and the selected client are referencing each other. If they do, they get removed and returned.
In the meantime clients can be added or removed by other threads.

The "ideal" solution would be to have a lock for every entry and lock the affected entries, every `clientChangedSelection` runs in it's own thread so they would wait if necessary. Of course that's not practical. On top of that, `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't offer apis to manually lock buckets as far as I know. And on top of that again, I've read somewhere that the buckets' locks aren't reentrant. Not sure if that's true or why.

My "imaginative" approach makes heavy use of nested `compute()` methods to guarantee atomicity. If `ConcurrentHashMap`'s locks aren't reentrant, this won't work. It loses any readability, requires "value capturing" workarounds, and performances are probably bad. But performances aren't much an issue as long as they don't affect threads working on unrelated entries. (i.e. in different buckets).

```java
public Client[] match(int id){
    final Client players[]=new Client[]{null,null};

    clients.computeIfPresent(id,(idA, playerA)->{
        if(playerA.selectedId!=idA){
            clients.computeIfPresent(playerA.selectedId,(idB, playerB)->{
                if(playerB.selectedId==idA){
                    players[0]=playerA;
                    players[1]=playerB;
                    return null;
                }else{
                    return playerB;
                }
            });
        }
        if(players[0]==null){
            return playerA;
        }else{
            return null;
        }
    });
    if(players[0]==null){
        return null;
    }else{
        return players;
    }
}
```

The "unacceptable" approach synchronizes the entire `match` method. This invalidates the point of having concurrent events in the first place.

The "wrong" approach temporarily removes the two clients while working with them, and adds them back in case. This makes concurrent events using the entries fail instead of waiting, as "in use" becomes indistinguishable from "not present".

I think I'll go back to a timer which inspects the whole map in one pass every n seconds. No additional synchronization would be required, but it's less elegant.

This is, more or less, a common concurrency situation, but it's made interesting by the `ConcurrentHashMap`, that discourages from reinventing too much the wheel.

What would your approach be? Any suggestions?

#### Edit 1

Synchronizing every access (thus defeating the point of using a *Concurrent*HashMap) is not a viable solution either. Concurrent access must be preserved, else the problem itself wouldn't exist.

I've removed the `selectedId` parameter from `match()`, but note that doesn't really matter. The fictitious event `clientChangedSelection(int whoChangedSelection)` represents the concurrent event. Could happen any time in any operating thread. `match()` is just an example function that gets called to handle the matching. Hope I made it clearer.

#### Edit 2

This is the doubly-synchronized function I ended up with. `idSelect()` is an example of a method that requires synchronization, as it modifies client attributes. Synchronization for `put()` and `remove()` is not required in this case, what the function sees is new enough.

There happens to be two checks: the first one is there just to get the clients to synchronize onto, the second one is there to tell if a previously executed match succeeded and removed the client, while the current one was waiting.

`match()` can't match the same client twice, and that was important (the atomic part).
`match()` can still match concurrently removed clients (removed with classic map apis, not by the same function), and that's tolerable.

```java
public void idSelected(int id, int selectedId){
    Client playerA=clients.get(id);
    if(playerA!=null){
        synchronized(playerA){
            playerA.selectedId=selectedId;
        }
    }
}

public Client[] match(int id, int selectedId){
    // determine if players exist in order be synchronized onto
    Client playerA=clients.get(id);
    if(playerA==null){
        return null;
    }
    Client playerB=clients.get(selectedId);
    if(playerB==null){
        return null;
    }
    // sort players in order to do nested synchronization safely
    if(id>selectedId){
        final Client t=playerA;
        playerA=playerB;
        playerB=t;
    }
    // check under synchronization
    synchronized(playerA){
        if(clients.containsKey(playerA.id)){
            synchronized(playerB){
                if(clients.containsKey(playerB.id)){
                    if(playerA.selectedId==playerB.id&&playerB.selectedId==playerA.id){
                        clients.remove(id);
                        clients.remove(selectedId);
                        return new Client[]{playerA,playerB};
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Suppose you're processing two clients. And meanwhile some other thread suddenly changes the reference of one of them (or remove the client). Somehow you notice this. What do you expect to happen in this case? Do you want to cancel current operation or you want to make the thread wait untill you're done with the clients?

Comment: `match()` has to be executed atomically on the two entries. While it's being executed, other threads that want to work on the same entries (or in the same buckets, in practice) have to wait.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest synchronizing on client objects themselves (synchronization on objects has to be performed in the same order to avoid deadlocks, you can use clientId to determine the order). That will let all the threads add\remove objects independently. And only those threads that require the same particular client will be synchronized.

Comment: You mean something like
```java
synchronize(clients.get(id)){
    synchronize(clients.get(selectedId)){
    //...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The only concern here is synchronization order.

Comment: Uh, I thought that wouldn't work. Also structure-altering methods like `remove`, don't need to be wrapped in a synchronize. cool. I'll try that tomorrow. I've *never* seen it done like that. I'll try to use integer comparison to guarantee the order, something like smaller first.

Comment: Actually, `remove` and `put` methods have to be synchronized, to ensure that you do not remove a client another thread is working on. This approach benefits from possibility to work independently and wins if you know there won't be many race conditions. Anyway, if you go a bit deeper, you can try to use optimistic locks and CAS (can search for it on the internet) and reduce the number of synchronizations required. But these approaches can be quite tricky.

Comment: Synchronizing on the objects doesn’t do anything useful if not all operations are synchronizing on the same objects, which would make the `ConcurrentHashMap` pointless. It’s not entirely clear what the method ought to do, e.g. `match` has a `selectedId` parameter that is not used at all. But your suspicion was right, nested `compute…` calls are not allowed. [“*The remapping function must not modify this map during computation.*”](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/15/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html#computeIfPresent(K,java.util.function.BiFunction))

Comment: In my specific case, it might be okay to synchronize "compound" operations only. It's ok for the map to be modified while a `match` is running, because `match` is working with what it found at the time of calling the two `.get`. It's not ok to have chains of waiting `match` that already `.get` the clients but in the meantime they got removed by a previous call. That could be mitigated by calling `.get` again *inside* the synchronized code. This way I do same-client-match scheduling but I preserve concurrent access. Throwing away the concurrency is not an option, I'll add that to the question.